# Going to a different view once photo selected from camera/library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am writing an app that has an initial view containing 2 buttons - one that allows the user to take a photo with the camera and the other that allows him to select a picture from the library.

I've written the code that allows that to happen, but after selecting the picture, I want to go to another view that allows, say, sharing the picture or whatever. Could anyone tell me how to do something like "whenPhotoIsSelected, view = newView"?

This is my code so far:

```
#pragma mark -
-(IBAction) getCameraPicture: (id) sender{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self; 
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES; 
picker.sourceType = (sender == takePictureButton) ?
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
```

}

I am aware of the existence of

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
```

but how exactly do I use it? I tried it and it crashes...

Comment: imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo: probably is the way to go here. Why did it crash? Can you provide source code?

Comment: I modified it for imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo but where do I call it? And what should the dictionary contain? The source code is in my post; I don't really know where to call the method...This code is part of the ViewController class implementation by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in your ViewController.
To do that add `<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>` to your ViewController's interface declaration (in the .h file) like so:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
// instance variable declarations etc.
}
```

Then in your ViewController's .m file you actually implement the method `-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo` instead of calling it, like so:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    // add the new view, for example you could push it on your navigation stack if you use a UINavigationController
}
```

That method will be called by the UIImagePicker when an image was selected.

Comment: It works :) Thanks! I just pushed the view and then it no longer hung once I chose a picture.

Comment: What happens now is that when I select the picture from library, it goes to the next view, but on top I also have "Go back to albums", which shouldn't be there. Can you tell me how to get rid of it?

Comment: Well if you use a UINavigationController you could send popViewControllerAnimated:NO to it before pushing the new UIViewController or you could just hide the navigationBar on top by sending setNavigationBarHidden:animated: to the UINavigationController or you just set your current view to the new view (self.view = newView).